# How to check if absolute value of two DATETIME fields difference is smaller then 30 seconds

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following line in SQL query in MySQL RDBMS

```
abs(timediff(tableA.enrollment_date, tableB.enrollment_date)) < 30 AND
```

This implies that the difference between times should not be more then `30 seconds`.

[Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) of MySQL tells that

> The result returned by TIMEDIFF() is limited to the range allowed for
>   TIME values. Alternatively, you can use either of the functions
>   TIMESTAMPDIFF() and UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), both of which return integers.

```
mysql> SELECT TIMEDIFF('2000:01:01 00:00:00',
    ->                 '2000:01:01 00:00:00.000001');
        -> '-00:00:00.000001'
mysql> SELECT TIMEDIFF('2008-12-31 23:59:59.000001',
    ->                 '2008-12-30 01:01:01.000002');
        -> '46:58:57.999999'
```

as per `abs()` I see that

> This function is safe to use with BIGINT values.

But now I have doubts about correctness of this.

Question: **How to check if absolute value of two DATETIME fields difference is smaller then 30 seconds?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method is:

```
(tableA.enrollment_date > tableB.enrollment_date - interval 30 second AND
 tableA.enrollment_date < tableB.enrollment_date + interval 30 second
)
```

Another method is to use `to_seconds()`:

```
abs(to_seconds(tableA.enrollment_date) - to_seconds(tableB.enrollment_date)) < 30
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use:

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,tableA.enrollment_date, tableB.enrollment_date)
BETWEEN -30 AND 30
```

It will give you the seconds between the two, please check the order of dates.